# Assembly Language X86 copy and clear upper half

Tags: assembly, x86

I need to copy bits 4-7 from AL into 0-3 of BL as well as clear the upper half of BOTH registers in two statements.

```
           SHLD   BL, AL, 4
```

should do the copy, but I don't know how to clear the upper 4 bits of both registers at once?

Comment: I don't believe `shld` works with single byte registers. I think it has to be either a word or a dword. eg. `ax` or `ebx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maby you can use Right shift operators. First shift bits in AL register (bits- 4,7) will be clear, and than copy register AL to BL.